# how to solve this issue ? Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in D:\

Tags: next.js, yarnpkg

```
PS D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world> yarn dev
yarn run v1.22.19
$ next dev
ready - started server on 0.0.0.0:3000, url: http://localhost:3000
info  - Using webpack 4. Reason: future.webpack5 option not enabled https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/webpack5
Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: Package subpath './lib/parser' is not defined by "exports" in D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\package.json
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:393:5)
    at throwExportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:358:9)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:27)
    at mod._resolveFilename (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\build\webpack\require-hook.js:4:1784)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at 552 (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11590)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at 270 (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:400)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735)
    at 327 (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:260)
    at __nccwpck_require__ (D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\dist\compiled\postcss-scss\scss-syntax.js:1:11735) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.




PS D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world> node -v
v18.12.1
```

getting this issue why i try to run a next js app (yarn dev)

and the content of "D:\NextJs\Next-JS-Tutorials\hello-world\node_modules\next\node_modules\postcss\package.json" is

```
{
  "name": "postcss",
  "version": "8.1.7",
  "description": "Tool for transforming styles with JS plugins",
  "engines": {
    "node": "^10 || ^12 || >=14"
  },
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "require": "./lib/postcss.js",
      "import": "./lib/postcss.mjs",
      "types": "./lib/postcss.d.ts"
    },
    "./": "./"
  },
  "main": "./lib/postcss.js",
  "types": "./lib/postcss.d.ts",
  "keywords": [
    "css",
    "postcss",
    "rework",
    "preprocessor",
    "parser",
    "source map",
    "transform",
    "manipulation",
    "transpiler"
  ],
  "funding": {
    "type": "opencollective",
    "url": "https://opencollective.com/postcss/"
  },
  "author": "Andrey Sitnik <andrey@sitnik.ru>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "homepage": "https://postcss.org/",
  "repository": "postcss/postcss",
  "dependencies": {
    "colorette": "^1.2.1",
    "line-column": "^1.0.2",
    "nanoid": "^3.1.16",
    "source-map": "^0.6.1"
  },
  "browser": {
    "./lib/terminal-highlight": false,
    "colorette": false,
    "fs": false
  }
}
```

Please help me to solve this

i tried removing the NODE-MODULES folder and the yarn-lock file and re running 'yarn' command .
but it is not helping